# Class with only 1 method, is it safe to let it handle it's own mutex?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, mutex

I have a very simple shared data structure with only one class, the idea being that every thread first aquire the mutex before doing an update:

```
class SharedData {
private:
    int * score;
    int n_loc;

public:
    mutex mutex;
    SharedData(int n_loc) : n_loc(n_loc) {
        score = new int[n_loc];
    }
    ~SharedData() {
        delete [] score;
    }
    void update_score(int * score2) {
        for(uint i = 0; i < n_loc; ++i) {
            score[i] = score2[i] = max(score[i], score2[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

Would it be ok for the class to handle it's own mutex, for example

```
void update_score_safe(int * score2, bool force_update = false) {
    if(force_update) mutex.lock();
    else if(!mutex.try_lock()) return;

    update_score(score2);

    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Is this this piece of code now thread safe? Will it prevent any code from calling the class without locking (given that I would make the mutex and the real update method private)?

Comment: If you're using `std::mutex`, then you might as well use `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: 1) Can't see any problem in this. And... yes, the code now is thread safe 2) Why don't you use `std::vector` ? 3) Maybe it would be better to return `bool` value from `update_score_safe` (`false` if `try_lock()` failed and `true` in other cases) ? 4) It seems to me that putting mutex in public is a very bad idea

Comment: @Mark great info, that one I wasn't aware of

Comment: @borisbn Thanks! As for 2) I benchmarked and in this case it is faster (and it needs to be fast). 3) Good point, i did implement that. 4) If you put the responsibility of aquiring the mutex to the caller, it should be public. Do you mean to say that this is always the way to go (aquiring the mutex inside the own class methods)?

Comment: @didierc, also if I make the update_score() method private?

Comment: nevermind my comments, I misread the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely; You need to ensure it is not copyable or assignable. Your 'mutex' may prohibit that (`std::mutex` does prohibit copying, which is sensible).

If it were copyable and/or assignable, then define the semantics; i.e. will not lock or will lock the source on copy/assign operations -- locking it would be the least surprising. Of course, it was not safe to copy as-is (double `delete[]`) but...

Also, I don't see anything wrong with an object abstracting synchronization -- it makes sense in some (not all) cases.

Answer (score 1):

1. I can't see any problem in your code. And... yes, the code now is thread safe (except you will throw some exceptions in `update_score`)
2. Maybe it would be better to return `bool` from `update_score_safe` (`false` if `try_lock()` failed and `true` in other cases) ?
3. It seems to me that putting mutex in public is a very bad idea
4. Why don't you use `std::vector` ?

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! 2) Good point, i did implement that. 3) If you put the responsibility of aquiring the mutex to the caller, it should be public. Do you mean to say that this is always the way to go (aquiring the mutex inside the own class methods)? 4 I benchmarked and in this case it is faster (and it needs to be fast).

Comment: @PeterSmit having the class handle its own mutex is a better solution. Otherwise everything can be broken from outside. The caller need not know there is a mutex at all.

Comment: @PeterSmit Even if mutex should be acquired outside your class (for example, if you should guard a couple of instances of your class at the same time), then the **caller** should create a mutex. I do not believe, that vector is slower in release (optimized) compilation. Proof it, please